# Define object from filename

Tags: r

Is there a way in R to define objects from filename?

I import data from many yearly files which have the same structure (one column per month and one row per day). Each of these files are named following this scheme: "Station_YYYY.txt", where YYYY is the number of the year (eg. 1985).

I have to merge this datasets so what I need before fusion is to add a column for the "Station" and a column for the "year".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctry
you do something like

```
a <- "Station_YYYY.txt"
dat<-read.csv(a,OTHER OPTIONS)
```

Just append station and year like this:

```
dat$station<-strsplit(a,"[._]")[[1]][1]
dat$year<-strsplit(a,"[._]")[[1]][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do a couple of simple loops...

For the following to work, make sure your local environment is empty because we will be searching for the '_' as a file name

```
setwd('') # direct R to where the files are stored
rm(list=ls())
files <- list.files()

for(file in files){
  name <- paste(file)
  name <- assign(name, read.csv(file))
}

data_sets <- grep('_', ls(), value = T)

allData <- data.frame()
for(i in data_sets){
  dat <- get(i)
  station_end <- data.frame(str_locate(i, '_'))$start - 1
  year_end <- data.frame(str_locate(i, '_'))$end + 4
  dat$station <- str_sub(i, 1, station_end)
  dat$year <- str_sub(i, station_end + 2, year_end)
  allData <- rbind(allData, dat)
}

allData
```